# How can I multiply two tibbles by column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have two tibbles with the same column names:

tb1:

```
   date        a     b     c     d     e
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2017-06-01  113.  182.  21.0  31.9  111.
```

tb2:

```
   date        a     b     c     d     e
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2016-05-01  122. 106.   23.9  43.7  93.5
2 2016-06-01  117. 111.   20.8  41.6  111. 
3 2016-07-01  116.  94.4  22.5  41.0  92.4
```

I want to multiply each row of tb2 by the respective number from tb1, is there a simple way to do this with dplyr or otherwise? I need to keep the dates from tb2 but I had dropped it from tb1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to scale well and deal with mismatched or out of order columns and the differing number of rows, I'd try reshaping the data. If you make both datasets into long formats, you'll have columns of a, b, c,... that you can use to join the datasets together. Keep the columns you need and reshape back to wide format.

I chose to use a left-join so that every row from tb2 (the one with more rows) will be kept, even if it doesn't have a matching row in tb1. I also set the suffix argument to make it more clear which dataset each column comes from.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(
  pivot_longer(tb2, -date),
  pivot_longer(tb1, -date),
  by = "name", suffix = c("2", "1")
) %>%
  mutate(value = value1 * value2) %>%
  select(date = date2, name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   date           a      b     c     d      e
#>   <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 2016-05-01 13786 19292   502. 1394. 10378.
#> 2 2016-06-01 13221 20202   437. 1327. 12321 
#> 3 2016-07-01 13108 17181.  472. 1308. 10256.
```

Comment: how do you read that text into data frames? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can make the rows in `tb1` and `tb2` equal and then multiply the two equal-sized dataframes.

```
cbind(tb2[1], tb1[rep(1, nrow(tb2)), -1] * tb2[-1])

#       date     a       b     c       d       e
#1 2016-05-01 13786 19292.0 501.9 1394.03 10378.5
#2 2016-06-01 13221 20202.0 436.8 1327.04 12321.0
#3 2016-07-01 13108 17180.8 472.5 1307.90 10256.4
```

If the columns in `tb1` and `tb2` are not in same order, we can first do

```
tb1 <- tb1[match(names(tb2), names(tb1))]
```

and then use the above.

**data**

```
tb1 <- structure(list(date = structure(1L, .Label = "2017-06-01", class = "factor"),
a = 113, b = 182, c = 21, d = 31.9, e = 111), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

tb2 <- structure(list(date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2016-05-01", 
"2016-06-01", "2016-07-01"), class = "factor"), a = c(122, 117, 
116), b = c(106, 111, 94.4), c = c(23.9, 20.8, 22.5), d = c(43.7, 
41.6, 41), e = c(93.5, 111, 92.4)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use base-R's `sweep` (check `?sweep` for its usage) on the numeric columns of `tb1` and `tb2` assuming that the columns are in the same order:

```r
## sweep multiplication
tb3 <- sweep(data.matrix(tb2)[, -1], MARGIN = 2, STATS = data.matrix(tb1)[, -1], FUN = "*")

## convert back to data.frame
cbind(date = tb2[, 1], as.data.frame(tb3))
#>         date     a       b     c       d       e
#> 1 2016-05-01 13786 19292.0 501.9 1394.03 10378.5
#> 2 2016-06-01 13221 20202.0 436.8 1327.04 12321.0
#> 3 2016-07-01 13108 17180.8 472.5 1307.90 10256.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution is to use `kronecker()` to expand the row in `tb1` to a matrix of the same size of `tb2[-1]`, i.e.,:

```
res <- cbind(tb2[1],kronecker(rep(1,nrow(tb2)),as.matrix(tb1[-1]))*tb2[-1])
```

such that

```
> res
        date     a       b     c       d       e
1 2016-05-01 13786 19292.0 501.9 1394.03 10378.5
2 2016-06-01 13221 20202.0 436.8 1327.04 12321.0
3 2016-07-01 13108 17180.8 472.5 1307.90 10256.4
```